# EventVwr.msc how to open automatically Application log

Tags: windows-7, event-viewer

I wonder whether there is a possibility to run eventvwr.exe with some parameters and automatically open Application log. (When I run it without parameters it displays Event viewer tree, there I can go manually into Windows Logs and select Application, however I would like to create a shortcut which will be selecting Application log automatically).

Answer (score 6):

I know this is dated but I found this question when searching for a different problem.
Long ago I found an easier way to do what you are asking, might be too late for you but maybe it helps someone else:

```
eventvwr.msc /c:Application
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you just made mistake in your typing, but it should be `eventvwr.msc` not `eventvwr.exe`.

Here's what I would do:

Open `eventvwr.msc` and choose `filter logs`.  Then create a filter to show what logs you want to see.  Then export the `xml` file with the filter data to somewhere in your `SYSTEM PATH` variable (`%PATH%`).  You should be able to call `evtviewer.msc yourxmlfilename.xml` and open.

This same result may be achievable also by using `mmc.exe` and building a custom snap-in, though I haven't tried doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The basics to view all the commands is go to Start / Run / type: cmd

At the DOS prompt type (without the quotes): `eventvwr /?`

Now you have a whole display of what you can play with for the `eventvwr.msc` command.

Comment: I believe you can get your first 10 or so points by simply filling out your profile. This discourages people from griefing by requiring just a little bit of effort before they can upvote and such.

Comment: At any rate, Super User doesn't work like a forum. I recommend that you read the [tour], to gain a little more insight on how this site works.

Comment: @music2myear No, you get badges for filling out your profile and so on. But you need reputation to post comments, vote, etc. and reputation can only be gained by getting upvotes to questions and/or answers.